# ZIPCODES data for all countries needed in Map chart on SPOTFIRE

Tags: maps, geocoding, spotfire, zipcode

I would like to know how can I add column with zipcodes from all countries to map chart on spotfire as there is no option to select the data for all countries. I see it is limited to only specific country's zipcodes like USA. I need something for the zipcodes of all countries.

I have the requirement to show the COST by Zipcodes across the globe.
Please help me in this custom geocoding data access on Map chart of spotfire.
I have country column, city column and zipcodes and no latitude or longitudes in my data set.

I tried checking the available geocoding options which were limited to only worldwide countries, cities and provinces and no data is available for zipcodes to match the column in my data table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.